# How to say in formal English that i am getting high salary in a few different way?

Tags: phrases

How to say in formal English that i am getting high salary in a few different way?

I am not very good in English.

Comment: Getting a (low/mid/high) six figure salary.  (Though of course in truly formal English it's rude to discuss one's wealth.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am **generously remunerated**.*

*I am **generously compensated** for my time.*

> Northern Ireland in the Second World War - Page 27 Brian Barton - 1995
>   - ‎Preview
>
> These included dispensing grants and subsidies, and setting up
>   parliamentary committees of enquiry (these could quite effectively
>   silence opponents, as members were **generously remunerated**).